# Selecting unique value in second repeating question- xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following sample XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <AllOptions Id="123"></AllOptions>
    <AllOptions Id="456"></AllOptions>
    <AllOptions Id="789"></AllOptions>
    <AllOptions Id="789"></AllOptions>
    <AllOptions Id="101"></AllOptions>
    <SelectedOptions>
        <SelectedOption Id="101" Selected="No"></SelectedOption>
        <SelectedOption Id="789" Selected="Yes"></SelectedOption>
        <SelectedOption Id="789" Selected="No"></SelectedOption>
        <SelectedOption Id="123" Selected="No"></SelectedOption>
        <SelectedOption Id="456" Selected="No"></SelectedOption>
    </SelectedOptions>
</root>
```

I am creating these in a tool that supports only XSLT1.0 and I am transforming these data using some XSLFO and XSL. I tried adding below a simplified version of what I have and some explanations:

- First, I am selecting `<AllOptions>` nodes;
- Inside this, I need to do a second loop after `<SelectedOption>` and match the `@Id` of `<SelectedOption>` node to `@Id` of `<AllOptions>`; then show only once the current `@Selected` attribute value

```
<xsl:template name="ShowOptions">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/AllOptions">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="../SelectedOptions/SelectedOption[@Id = current()/@Id]">
            <fo:block> <xsl:value-of select="@Selected"/> </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

With the above template, I am getting the values from below. This is not correct because there are nodes that can have same @Id, in this example this is @Id=789, and @Selected will be duplicated.

```
123 
   No
456
   No
789
   Yes
   No
789
   Yes
   No
101
   No
```

What I need is to show the current @Selected value

```
123 
   No
456
   No
789
   Yes
789
   No
101
   No
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are two `<AllOptions Id="789">` and two `<SelectedOption Id="789">`. Do you imply a 1:1 correspondence between these? If so, how is it defined? Which corresponds to which?

Comment: What if there are two `<SelectedOption Id="789" Selected="Yes"></SelectedOption>`? What would be the output in that case?

Comment: In this case, I am looking to show both with a `Yes` value:  the first Id with `789` and the value `Yes`, and below it, the second Id with same `789` and its current value that will be `Yes` too.

Comment: Does it even need to use `AllOptions`. Your expected output seems to have all values  from `SelectedOption` elements. Also as your above comment says, if `SelectedOption` repeats just repeat in the output with its values. In that case, just have one loop on `SelectedOption` elements, may be use `<xsl:sort>` if need to sort the output by `@Id` values.